# requesttimeout on pinging the server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

We have a server where a application is running. Some data entries are going on in one of our office site and the application is going too slow. They ping the server and its getting request time out at regular intervals. Also traceroute is showing a request timeout. But when we are pinging the server from our office, everythg looks fine. What can be the problem at their end? 
Traceroute is showing request timeout at 4th step and it carries on to the server.

Answer (score 1):

You can get request timeout on intermediary node in a traceroute if these specific devies are setup not to answer to ICMP ECHO themselves. Furthermore, some firewall will only allow a limited number of ICMP ECHO requests per second on a particular path.

In your case, I would get the full path from your remote office and compare them: it is possible that you have a split path issue and that your packets aren't going through the same route in one way and the other. This is usually due to incorrect router configuration but can also be due to a VPN configuration problem or even a multi-homed server with an incorrect netmask.

Answer (score 0):

I echo Stephane's answer.  You don't give much information regarding the sites, and where the server actually is.  Once you've established the route between the failing client(s) and the server, connect to a client/server in the last successful hop and try pinging different subnets from their.  It might be a route not properly defined in that site's router(s).

Ideally, you need some input from your data guys.